# How to stop NodeJS printing GET requests to the console

Tags: node.js, console.log

NodeJs is printing each GET request (.js files, .css files, etc.) to the console.

```
...   
    GET /plugins/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js 304 0.652 ms - -
    GET /plugins/jquery.validate.js 304 0.434 ms - -
    GET /plugins/vide/jquery.vide.js 304 0.910 ms - -
    GET /plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js 304 0.700 ms - -
...
```

Is there a way to stop Node printing these to the console?

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "ExPlatform",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "~1.12.0",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.4",
    "debug": "~2.1.1",
    "ejs": "~2.3.1",
    "express": "~4.12.2",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "gm": "^1.21.1",
    "imagemagick": "^0.1.3",
    "mongoose": "^4.3.7",
    "mongoose-crate": "^1.0.10",
    "mongoose-crate-localfs": "^1.1.1",
    "morgan": "~1.5.1",
    "multer": "^1.1.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.0",
    "jsonfile": "^2.3.0",
    "nodemailer": "^2.4.2",
    "fast-csv": "^2.0.0",
    "fluent-logger": "^1.1.1"
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Show you package.json dependency (not devDependency) list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it was the `morgan` module that was doing this.
I had `app.user(logger('dev'))`;

Answer (score 1):

It's [`helmet`](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet) package that uses [`connect`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) package underneath which uses `debug` package which logs every http request, just remove this line

```
var helmet = require('helmet');
app.use(helmet());
```

And uninstall it using `npm uninstall helmet --save`

Also morgan is used to log, check it out too https://github.com/expressjs/morgan

Comment: Thank you Medet. But I don't seem to be using helmet in my app. Do you think it is 'debug' package? I tried removing 'debug' but that didn't help.

Comment: Deleting debug doesn't make sense - because it's in peer dependency, find the connect or helmet package usages

Comment: Seems it is the 'morgan' package that is doing this. I had app.use(logger('dev'). Once that was removed it stopped the GET printouts. Thank you Medet.